# Is there a way to store a hex value of FF in a register in LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am trying to store the hex value FF in a register but I am getting a error "immediate 'xFF' out of range"

Answer (score 2):

If the constant were much smaller (i.e in the range -16..+15 decimal, aka x-10 to xF), you could clear a register first, and then use the `ADD` with immediate form.  But your constant is too large for that.  (And this would take two instructions, depending on your larger code sequence.)

---

Otherwise, LC-3 uses (pc-relative) memory based addressing modes — there is no load immediate!  You'll have to store the value xFF in memory, give it a label, and `LD` (load) it from memory.

```
     LD R3, labelFF
     ...

labelFF, .fill xFF
```

---

Of course, this is assuming you want the 16-bit constant 0x00FF.  If you wanted -1 (0xFFFF) there would be more options since that is a small negative value, and the immediates are sign extended.

Still, `LD` with label is a proper way to load constants into registers on LC-3.